# Why is the object not saving in javascript and parse?

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I am trying to create a new objet and save it, but I get this when I try and save it `{"_resolved":false,"_rejected":false,"_resolvedCallbacks":[],"_rejectedCallbacks":[]}`.

```
function saves(cent, dollar){

var se = Parse.Object.extend("Money");
var newse = new se();

newse.set("cent", cent);
newse.set("dollar", dollar);

newse.save(null,{
   success: function (object) { 
    status.success(object);
  }, 
  error: function (object, error) { 
    status.error(error);
  }
 });
}
```

Comment: That looks like a promise. You'd register a callback for when it's settled by using `.then` on it.

Comment: *"...but I get this..."* From **what**? `newse.save`?

Comment: So after the `})` I would do a `.then`?

Comment: Yes from `console.log(newse.save());`

Comment: you do realize that [parse.com is shutting down soon](http://blog.parse.com/announcements/moving-on/)?

Comment: Yes I am very aware.

Answer (score 0):

What you've described looks like a `Promise`. To use it, you register a callback (or two) via `then`:

```
newse.save(null).then(
    function() {
        // This is called when the promise is resolved (success)
    },
    function() {
        // This is called when the promise is *rejected* (failure)
    }
);
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to save

Comment: @manatee: What makes you say that? What are you looking at, etc.?

Comment: I am checking the class to see if there is a new row and there isn't

Comment: @manatee: Can't help with that part I'm afraid. I can only explain the return value you're getting: It's a `Promise`.

Comment: hmm. Also nothing is getting printed when I add a console.log("success") or error in the code you provided

Comment: @manatee: What you've shown in your question is clearly a promise, and this is how promises work. That's all I can say.

Comment: When I console the above code you provided, I get the same error I posted in the original question.

Comment: @manatee: **Again**: What you've shown is clearly a promise. This is how you use promises. Can't help beyond that.